# Dynamically add various controls to scrollview (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, dynamic-controls

I'm working on a web application which allows the users to customize the fields they want to retrieve from their users.  For example, text, numbers, booleans, popups.  Because its unknown the amount of controls I need decided to create a reference to a scrollview.  I tried adding a button as a test but I can't figure out how to get the button to show up? When I view the page I see just white.

**How do I add dynamic controls to a scrollview?**

Things I tried:

- Made sure AutoLayout is correct for the scrollView.
- The addSubview code below.

  ```
  import UIKit
  class TaskDetailViewController: UIViewController {


      @IBOutlet weak var theScrollView: UIScrollView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
          //self.view.addSubview(UIButton)

          let cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 30))
          cellButton.setTitle("hello", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

          theScrollView.addSubview(cellButton)
      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
          super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
          // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }


      /*
      // MARK: - Navigation

      // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
      override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
          // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
          // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
      }
      */

  }
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear this IS the correct way to do it.  Apparently the text is white by default so I couldn't see the button.

Adding this line

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

made the button visible.  As my question asks for how to add various controls this can be done and still follow autolayout views by using constraints programatically.  There is a good video on the topic here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bl_YZLKPg1c), make sure to watch part 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a better practice to add a ContainerView under Scrollview, and put all your subviews inside ContainerView?

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to the question or is this just a comment?